# http.request & pipe dont fire after error event touched

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, pipe

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(req, res) {
    var headers = req.headers;
    var host = req.headers.host.split(':')

    var options = {
        hostname: host[0],
        port: host[1]===undefined?80:Number(host[1]),
        path: req.url,
        method: 'GET'
    }
    var proxy=http.request(options, function(pres){
        pres.pipe(res, {end: true})
    })
    proxy.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err);
    })

    req.pipe(proxy, {end:true});
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
```

I try to make forward http proxy, this's my code.
my problem is: when I try to connect whoer.net (I'm using firefox), in source of page it contains some like do-not-exist-domain.com, so 'error' event be called. It's ok at here excluse that my browser do not stop waiting for data from connection.
I think It happen because when error event called, connection is still open and browser will wait until timeout got. Do I think correct? and how to fix it :D
Thank you for advance

Comment: try adding `res.end()` inside the `error` callback

Comment: @levi excellent answer!! you save my day!!! I forgot that req and res handle only one connection, so I dont try to call res.end(). Thank you very much!